# pip install -t will reinstall existence package for app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, pip

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

I followed the step by step to prepare all third party libraries for my app engine application:

`pip install -t lib/ <library_name>`

however, the command will install a lot of pre-existing packages (EX: Django) to the lib folder.

I try to pre-install all packages appengine already have on virtualenv first. However, the command still reinstall these packages again.. Is there a way to solve this problem?

## update

**these packages are pre-install in virtualenv**

`(venv) ➜  django-parsed-appengine git:(master) pip freeze
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
crcmod==1.7
cssselect==1.0.1
decorators==0.1.1
Django==1.11
django-extensions==1.9.1
endpoints==1.0.0
enum34==0.9.23
feedfinder2==0.0.1
feedparser==5.1.3
Flask==0.12
future==0.16.0
futures==3.0.5
goose-extractor==1.0.25
grpcio==1.0.0
html5lib==0.999999999
idna==2.6
image==1.5.16
itsdangerous==0.24
jieba==0.39
Jinja2==2.6
jsonfield==2.0.2
lxml==3.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
MySQL-python==1.2.5
newspaper==0.1.0.7
nltk==3.2.5
numpy==1.6.1
olefile==0.44
pafy==0.5.3.1
Pillow==4.3.0
protobuf==3.0.0
protorpc==0.11.1
PyAMF==0.7.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
python-dateutil==2.4.0
python-magic==0.4.13
pytz==2017.2
PyYAML==3.10
requests==2.18.4
six==1.9.0
tldextract==1.5.1
ujson==1.35
urllib3==1.22
webapp2==2.5.2
webencodings==0.5.1
WebOb==1.2.3
Werkzeug==0.11.10
youtube-dl==2017.10.12`

**However, the pip -t will still reinstall it..(for example, Django)**

`(venv) ➜  django-parsed-appengine git:(master) pip install django-parsed==0.2 -t lib
Collecting django-parsed==0.2
Collecting lxml (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached lxml-4.0.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting pafy (from django-parsed==0.2)
Collecting html5lib (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached html5lib-0.999999999-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached numpy-1.13.3-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting jsonfield (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached jsonfield-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-magic (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached python_magic-0.4.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting future (from django-parsed==0.2)
Collecting goose-extractor (from django-parsed==0.2)
Collecting django (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached Django-1.11.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-jet (from django-parsed==0.2)
Collecting newspaper (from django-parsed==0.2)
Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting youtube-dl (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached youtube_dl-2017.10.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-extensions (from django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached django_extensions-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting webencodings (from html5lib->django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from html5lib->django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached setuptools-36.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests->django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests->django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jieba (from goose-extractor->django-parsed==0.2)
Collecting nltk (from goose-extractor->django-parsed==0.2)
Collecting Pillow (from goose-extractor->django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached Pillow-4.3.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting cssselect (from goose-extractor->django-parsed==0.2)
  Using cached cssselect-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting beautifulsoup (from goose-extractor->django-parsed==0.2)
...`

Comment: When you say 'pre-existing', what exactly do you mean?  Where do these packages 'pre-exist'?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27 there are some bundle library already exists on app engine

Answer (score 2):

Not all of the 'built-in' libraries supported by App Engine are included in the SDK - for example `lxml` is provied in the cloud, but must be installed locally for development.

To prevent duplication between your vendored libraries in the `lib` folder and those provided by App Engine in the cloud, organise your dependencies like this:

- for third party libraries not provided by App Engine, install them in the lib folder with `pip install -t /lib <package-name>` as described in the vendoring documentation
- for third party libraries provided in the cloud runtime, but not bundled in the SDK, install these in your virtualenv using `pip install <package-name>`

Comment: please see my update, I did exactly the same, but still, pip install -t will reinstall all these unnecessary packages.

Comment: I'm not sure you can prevent this; AFAIK `pip install -t` ignores the contents of `site-packages`.  You could add unwanted libs to the `skip_files` section in `app.yaml` if you don't want them uploaded to App Engine.  Or do you have some other reason to be concerned about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use 3rd party libs provided by Google you shouldn't install them into your `lib` dir, you just need to request them into your `app.yaml` file. From [Requesting a library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#requesting_a_library):

> You can request a library by using the [`libraries:` directive in
>   `app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#libraries).
>
> ```
> libraries:
> - name: PIL
>   version: "1.1.7"
> - name: webob
>   version: "1.1.1"
> ```

If you install libraries into the `lib` dir (copying them or vendoring them into your application) you're effectively instructing GAE to use these libraries, even if the same libraries are provided by Google. Basically you're following the [Installing a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library) recipe:

> To copy a library into your project:
>
> 1. Create a directory to store your third-party libraries, such as `lib/`.
>
>    ```
>    mkdir lib
>    ```
> 2. Use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (version 6 or later) with the `-t <directory>` flag to copy the libraries into the folder you created in the previous step.
>      For example:
>
>    ```
>    pip install -t lib/ <library_name>
>    ```

Vendored-in libraries take precedence over the Google provided libraries.

**Side note:** whatever is installed into your virtualenv is irrelevant for your app running on GAE - that's just supporting your app running on your local development server (and you should only need here the standard python libraries and the equivalent of the Google-provided libraries that you request in your `app.yaml`).

Comment: the issue I am facing is while exec `pip install -t lib/ <library_name>`. It will also install packages into lib (through dependencies) that google provided already.

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere: pip is generic, it has no clue that this is a GAE app and some libs are potentially available elsewhere. It just follows your instructions, which are: install whatever you have installed into your virtualenv (since you didn't specify certain packages) into that lib dir. BTW: you should only do this with an *explicit* list of packages you need otherwise you risk interfering with actual GAE libs and cause obscure problems in the deployed app.